# jquery serialize dynamic input

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to see how I can pass a dynamic input type through serialize and be processed in my ajax php page for return via json. As you see, it is made up of a for loop which increments each input based on a slider. I cannot just process id="BRV-brtrv-boxamount- because it dosen't recognise it. I would be grateful if someone could help me with this. Thanks

```
for(var i = 0;i < $(this).val();i++) {
   $("#BRV-brtrv-boxnumber").append('<div data-role="fieldcontain"><label for="BRV-brtrv-boxamount" class="ui-input-text">Enter box ' + (i + 1) + ' number:</label><input type="text" name="BRV-brtrv-boxamount-' + i + '-no" id="BRV-brtrv-boxamount-' + i + '-no" class="BRV-brtrv-boxamount ui-input-text ui-body-null ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset ui-body-a" required="required" /></div>')
   }
```

+++EDIT+++

```
$(function() {

 $("#BRV_brtrv").submit(function() {

   var send = $(this).serialize();

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "boxrtrvajax.php",
      cache: false,
      data: send,
      dataType: "json",
      success: function (msg) {

      $('#brtv-result').addClass("result_msg").html(msg.service);

     },
     error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
      jAlert('There was an exception thrown somewhere');
      alert(xhr.status);
      alert(thrownError);
     }
   });
   return false;
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var url = 'my.ajax.php';
var params = new Object();

$('input, select').each(function () {
  params[this.name] = this.value;      
}); 

$.post(url, params);
```

since you provided a complete exemple, here is the complete answer:

```
$(function() {

 $("#BRV_brtrv").submit(function() {

   var send = $(this).serialize();

   $.getJSON("boxrtrvajax.php", send, function(msg) {
      $('#brtv-result').addClass("result_msg").html(msg.service);
   })
   .error(function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
      jAlert('There was an exception thrown somewhere');
      alert(xhr.status);
      alert(thrownError);
   });

   return false;
  });

});
```

but your example shall work too. note: you can use $.post() instead of $.getJson() (or even $.get(), as both $.get and $.post are able to recognize and parse json response if there is one).

Comment: roselan thank you. I am quite new to jquery and would be grateful if you could show me where in my code that would work. I have added code to my question. Thanks

Comment: I had a "slight" error in my code (the $.get inside the loop). sorry (and edited)

Comment: roselan I am sorry but i am not following you. Why do I need var url = 'my.ajax.php'; if i am posting to url? does your code just appear on top of mine. Thanks

Comment: I didn't see your javascript code since you added it, now i did

Comment: roslean coming back to my earlier comment, do I need to use your code with my code or have you modified my code in your answer? thanks